# I want to get GMAIL spams identified, in desktop client, with pop3

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, pop3

I know IMAP solves the problem, but I don't want to use it. I want to have the gmail spam received inbox (already done that) but I want it in a way that my desktop email program can recognize it as gmail spam. I'm using eM Client now.

Some toughts:

1) if I could use a marker/label in gmail that the desktop program recognizes as so, it would automatically (rule) send it to a spam folder.

2) I've tried searching for a way of adding something in the subject of received messages in gmail but didn't found a solution (for ex, if marked in the filter then add [IS_SPAM] in the subject).

3) I've found some controversy information about eM Client and how it talks with gmail, where I tought it could do something with gmail labels/markers but I'm not very sure and couldn't implement it.

Comment: eM Client supports Google's labels.  All SPAM is is a label.  Any email with the SPAM label is spam.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound Well my first question was whether there was technology in eM client for that. Now that you confirmed so, could you please explain me how to use it? I must use a gmail filter for "is:spam" to keep messages in the inbox right, but I don't know how to work with eM client to detect those messages? nor any "label"

Comment: I don't use the client.  But based on the features the program has it was design to support Google Mail labels.